# BibTex Bibiography: Referencing web resources

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx, jabref

I inserted a BibTeX bibiography from JabRef to my LyX document.I need to cite a web resource.

In JabRef, I tried to insert the web reference manually as below.

```
@Electronic{iecwhitepaper,
  note         = {(Accessed on 29th May 2020)},
  url          = {https://www.iec.ch/basecamp/internet-things-wireless-sensor-networks},
  organization = {IEC},
  title        = {Title},
  year         = {2014},
}
```

However, in the LyX output, the reference only displays the title. Would anyone please suggest how to display it as "Title. Available online: URL (accessed on Day Month Year). "?

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Please also indicate why the enry has `organization = {IEC},` instead of `author = {{International Electrotecnical Commission}}`.

Comment: @Mico, I left that empty because the journal instruction is "keep empty the Style field." There is no author name in that document. That's why I was not sure where to write it.

Comment: Well, it's simply not possible to generate a bibliography with BibTeX *unless* one specifies a bibliography style. If the journal gives out nonsense instructions, you have no choice but to ignore them.

Comment: @Mico, then please suggest me any suitable style with what I will get the desired referencing style.

Comment: I'm not sure why you claim that the piece has no `author`, given that "International Electrotechnical Commission" is displayed rather prominently on the webpage in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journal's suggestion not to employ a `\bibliographystyle` directive makes no sense, as without such a directive one cannot even begin to create a bibliography via BibTeX.

To keep things as generic as possible, I would like to suggest the following work-around: (a) load the `cite` citation management package (it'll generate numeric-style citation call-outs) and (b) employ a bibliography style -- say, `plainnat` -- that knows what to do when it encounters a field called `url`.

The journal's editorial staff should have no problems with this setup, as it's trivially easy to employ a different citation management package and a different bibliography style and then run a full recomplie cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to generate a new pdf file that reflects the journal's preferred settings regarding the formatting of bibiographic entries and the style of citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@Electronic{iecwhitepaper,
  note         = {(Accessed on 29 May 2020)},
  url          = {https://www.iec.ch/basecamp/internet-things-wireless-sensor-networks},
  author       = {{International Electrotechnical Commission}},
  title        = {{Internet of Things}: Wireless Sensor Networks},
  year         = {2014},
  
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow linebreaks at arbitrary places in a URL string

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{iecwhitepaper}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```